# Facebook integration with suitecrm

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I need facebook feed and Facebook posts in suitecrm. For this, I have done with the following steps. 
I have added the facebook app key and secret key in connector and also enabled the modules which i want in connector enable. 
After this on  suite dashboard i got login button but after login Facebook feed is not appeared. Please let me know is it possible to get feed in suitecrm?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate facebook with suitecrm

check this officail link :

https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/03/25/integrating-facebook-with-sugarcrm-how-to-setup-a-facebook-cloud-connector/